# Is there a way to know if a WorkManager Job did not execute because of a constraint?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Right now I have some jobs on the `WorkManager` that uses this constraint.

```
wifiConstraint = Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.UNMETERED)
                .build()

work_version = "2.2.0"
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$project.work_version"
```

The customers device seems to be connected to a WiFi network but the Job is not getting dispatched (it's set to `repeatInterval: 30, TimeUnit.MINUTES`) after 6 hours.

This WiFi network is an enterprise network with a configuration profile.

Is there a way to know if the Job did not meet an established constraint, and which constraint did not meet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## April 9th 2020 Update

[WorkManager v2.4.0 alpha 01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#2.4.0-alpha01) introduces the ability to request diagnostic information from WorkManager using

```
adb shell am broadcast -a "androidx.work.diagnostics.REQUEST_DIAGNOSTICS" -p "<your_app_package_name>".
```

This provides a lot of useful information including:

- WorkRequests that were completed in the last 24 hours.
- WorkRequests that are currently RUNNING.
- Scheduled WorkRequests. (aosp/1235501)

This is only available on debug builds.

**Follow original answer, still valid for older WorkManager version and for release builds.**

You cannot get this informations directly in WorkManager, but, assuming that this device is running on Android 6.0+ (API level23+), you can get some information about the underlying JobScheduler API used by WorkManager.

Using the command:

`adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler`

You should be able to identify your task with this command.

This will give you a huge output in following categories.

- Settings
- Registered XX Jobs
- Connectivity
- Alarms
- Idle
- Battery
- AppIdle
- Content
- Job history
- Pending queue

If you are testing on Android 7.1 and higher, then you can force-run a scheduled job using the following command.

```
adb shell cmd jobscheduler run -f PACKAGE_NAME JOB_ID
```